# Can I connect Windows 8 to a Server 2003 domain?

Tags: windows-8, windows-domain

Before I go ahead and install Windows 8, will it connect to a Server 2003 domain. I know Windows 7 connects fine, and there is no technical reason that Windows 8 can't, but that doesn't mean it will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Windows 8 will connect just fine to a Server 2003 domain, and you can then link your Domain Account(s) to a Microsoft Account to enable all of the Windows 8 online features.

Answer (score 2):

You can add it to a 2003 domain, but, just as in 2008 systems, you will be limited to the capabilities of the older domain. If you want all the latest capabilities, especially when it comes to Group Policy, you will want to update your domain to a Server 2012 platform.

At this stage of the process, only Server 2012 has the necessary components to have complete group policy control over Windows 8. On older domains you can only make policies that have been carried over from Windows 7. Microsoft may release this capability later on, but I personally have not seen anything from Microsoft about it.

Answer (score 0):

The only one thing to note is that some Windows 8 systems will struggle with VPN to a 2003 server until the security protocols are amended

You need to set to " Send LM and NTLM responses only" and disable 123-bit encryption.   Will do the trick.

I faced this earlier, but have since taken steps to upgrade RARA server to 2008

Ta

Comment: The OP asks about connecting/using WIN 8 with a 2003 server but not specifically about a VPN connection